# Not receiving money in Stripe test transactions (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So I created subscriptions in my Rails app with test API keys from Stripe.
The charges I'm creating with dummy cards are going through successfully on my side, but when I'm in Stripe dashboard, the test balance remains the same, as well customer details are not added. I'm not sure what I did wrong.. Do you know why I can't and how can I add those test customer data to Stripe? In the logs, I'm getting 200 OK response, but I'm worried that something isn't going to function in live mode since test balance isn't being updated.

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController

   before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def new
    end

    def update

      token = params[:stripeToken]

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          card: token,
          plan: 1020,
          email: current_user.email
          )
        current_user.subscribed = true
        current_user.stripeid = customer.id
        current_user.save

        redirect_to profiles_user_path
    end


end
```

and _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag profiles_user_path, method: :get do %>


<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="8999"></script><span> $89 per month </span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors, either in your Rails logs, or your browser console when you call the update action?

Comment: No, everything is going smoothly on my side, I'm not getting any errors and I am using test api keys..

Comment: What about your logs in the Stripe dashboard?

Comment: I'm getting status 200, this is part of response body: tok_18BPCiAwJUZIqFavuf8fN27f
object: "token"
card:
id: card_18BPCiAwJUZIqFavCQ2TFbIr
object: "card"
brand: "Visa"
country: "US"
cvc_check: "pass"
dynamic_last4: null
exp_month: 11
exp_year: 2018
funding: "credit"
last4: "4242"
metadata:
name: "test@gmail.com"
tokenization_method: null
email: "test@gmail.com"
livemode: false
type: "card"
used: false

Comment: And the customers tab is empty?

Comment: yes... I'm not sure what's going on... maybe the customer details are not being saved was my guess..

Comment: And if you run `Stripe::Token.retrieve("tok_18BPCiAwJUZIqFavuf8fN27f") ` do you get an object back? What about `Stripe::Customer.list`? If the API responds with 200 then that should mean the object is created. Also, stupid question, but you're sure the Stripe console is in 'test' mode?

Comment: yup it's a test mode and yes the object is created..

Comment: So it seems as though the issue is with the Stripe dashboard if you're able to retrieve created objects using the API.

Comment: Ok will contact them to see what's going on! Will keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: Same problem here, I integrated it yesterday and it worked, but now it doesn't show charges, only created customers. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using your Stripe test API keys, and not your live keys. These can be found in the "API keys" section of your account settings from the Stripe dashboard:

[image]

So the API keys you're using should include `_test_`.

For testing, you should also consider using StripeMock, which runs a virtual Stripe server to emulate Stripe: https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock.

**EDIT**

If you're still getting errors, then check your stripe logs and provide a redacted copy here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It took my almost a year to find this out.

I was using **tipsi-stripe** on my **react-native app**, only.

I was not aware I needed to send the **token** to my own backend.  And my backend needed to communicate with stripe REST API in order to use that token and create a payment out of that.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges